# Why Hilt isn't necessary for unit tests, but it is necessary for UI tests?

Tags: android, unit-testing, dependency-injection, ui-testing, dagger-hilt

[Hilt testing guide documentaton](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing) has this paragraph about Unit test

> Hilt isn't necessary for unit tests, since when testing a class that uses constructor injection, you don't need to use Hilt to instantiate that class. Instead, you can directly call a class constructor by passing in fake or mock dependencies, just as you would if the constructor weren't annotated:

```
@ActivityScoped
class AnalyticsAdapter @Inject constructor(
  private val service: AnalyticsService
) { ... }

class AnalyticsAdapterTest {

  @Test
  fun `Happy path`() {
    // You don't need Hilt to create an instance of AnalyticsAdapter.
    // You can pass a fake or mock AnalyticsService.
    val adapter = AnalyticsAdapter(fakeAnalyticsService)
    assertEquals(...)
  }
}
```

But [here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing#ui-test) you can see that documentation is explaining how to use Hilt in UI test.

My question is why Hilt isn't necessary for unit tests, but it is necessary for UI tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With unit tests you verify behavior inside the classes, while in UI test you verify UI state given data. In unit test you don't need Hilt to generate a object tree, you are testing a small building unit of your app, a class, a function. Your unit test have limited scope of objects needed, so that's another reason why you don't need Hilt to build entire tree of objects each unit test.

In unit test you verify that an event have happened, a function has been called or a result has been returned given an input.

Hilt is injecting fake components in your UI test through which you are providing data that is rendered.

Comment: Thanks. I faced this after I asked this question pragmatically and I can approve that we don't need to fake components in the Unit test

Comment: There is no widely accepted definition for a unit in a unit test, it doesn't necessarily have to be written for a single class or a small number of classes but rather can be written for a feature / use case as well which can span a large number of classes.

Comment: On personal projects I've moved from hilt to koin for precisely the reason that hilt philosophy on unit tests just doesn't work for me. UI tests for non view related stuff are too expensive, and robolectric, in addition to other problems out there ties you to junit4

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment written here on the accepted answer

> There is no widely accepted definition for a unit in a unit test, it doesn't necessarily have to be written for a single class or a small number of classes but rather can be written for a feature / use case as well which can span a large number of classes. @suyash

Here is how to do it.

**To be be able to "unit test" a feature / use case, you can still use the setup of Hilt without having Hilt run and generate a graph.**

For instance:

- Module A has a test that verifies a use case but the use case is injected with a class from module B.
- That class in module B is actually an interface plus an internal class implementation. So you cannot directly instantiate it.

Module B code:

```
interface MyInterface {}

internal class MyObjectFromB() : MyInterface {}
```

And Module B's hilt setup:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object MyBModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideMyInterface(): MyInterface = MyObjectFromB()

}
```

In Module A you would like to do this:

```
@Test
fun `some test`() {
    assertTrue( MyObjectFromA(MyObjectFromB()).foo() )
}
```

but `MyObjectFromB` is `internal` to ModuleB so from ModuleA you can't, but it does not stop you using the Module classes (`MyBModule`) yourself:

```
@Test
fun `some test`() {
    assertTrue( MyObjectFromA(MyBModule.provideMyInterface()).foo() )
}
```

I'm not saying its perfect :-) but it **allows you to have an integration test style unit test whilst avoiding running Hilt and also keeping module encapsulation**.